# How To Upload Images In Virtual Directory From REST SERVER

Tags: java, android, rest, tomcat

I am Using Apache Tomcat with JERSEY REST SERVER.
Iam Able to upload images to a folder on the server,But i need to save images To a Virtual Dirtectory created on  my server.
I came across this post:http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=790
but have no idea how to go about.
My Web.Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>ProjectName</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```